# Recursively archive small files in document tree on linux?

Tags: linux, files, archive

Given a base directory (like `/home/user`) is there a command that could be run which would create an archive back up all text files (i.e. files less than 100kb) in that directory and it's children? I know you can tar/gz a directory - but what about excluding files also?

The idea is that most photos, videos, and other large files would be ignored while all important hand-typed documents could easily be backed up quickly when moving around projects and servers.

**UPDATE**

Using skinp's awesome code I was able to backup a small amount of the files. However, as DerfK pointed out - there is a limit to the size of arguments you can pass to commands. With that in mind I was able to write out the contents of `find` hoping that I could use something to read the contents to `tar` and bypass this limit. The other other option seems to be a sh script that could ad each file to the archive at a time.

```
find /home/username -type f -size -100k > list.of.small.files.txt
```

*Which rendered out a 6MB file.*

Comment: too tired to build a whole solution: have a look at `tar`, `find` and `xargs`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the other answers posted here so far, I'm concerned that the uses I see of `xargs` and `find -exec {}` are erroneous. If and when the file list grows long enough that `tar -c` is executed by `xargs` more than once, the tar file populated to that point will be overwritten. Thus, only the files from the last invokation of `tar` will end up in the tarfile.

Here's a one-liner that should always work, regardless of the total number of files, and regardless of whether filenames contain embedded newlines:

```
find /home/user -type f -size -100k -print0 | tar -c -z --null --files-from=- -f backup.tgz
```

The `find` command generates a list of null-terminated file names to backup, and the `tar` command reads that list from the pipe and creates the tarfile `backup.tgz`.

Comment: Awesome, next thing I knew I had a 100MB backup of text files sitting there.

Answer (score 3):

I would use the power of find:

```
find /home/user -type f -size -100k -exec tar cvzf backup.tgz {} \+
```

type: specifies you want a file not a directory
size: with the number preceeded by -, means we want less than 100k
exec: execute the tar with {} being the files found, \+ means end of the exec

You could also use xargs:

```
find /home/user -type f -size -100k | xargs tar cvzf backup.tgz
```

**Update:**

tar as a command to append a file to an existing tar archive (maybe even not existing, it works for me).

Here's a simple example script doing this:

```
find . -type f -size -100k -print > filelist
for i in `cat filelist`
do
    tar --append $i --file=backup.tar
done
gzip backup.tar
```

Obviously, this script is highly ineficient... It only append one file at a time, launching the tar command as many time as there is files.
It would be good to script it in a way that it append say 1000 files each pass...

Comment: You will have a lot of `tar`s :-)

Comment: From what I remember, \+ means execute the command once for all that was found, \; means execute the command each time something is found. I tried it and it worked... could be system dependent I guess though.

Comment: Both work, (using lain's modifications) so which would be better/faster on large directories?

Comment: You are right actually. Didn't notice the `+`

Comment: @Xeoncross both options are essentially equivalent, but the `xargs` option requires starting a third program (xargs) so could be a few ms slower.  Also, by "large" do you mean *really large*?  Be careful, if you have more than 131k or so files you'll hit the ARG_MAX limit on commandline arguments with either the xargs or the find command and you'll need a different option for getting them all in the tarball.  See http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/#results

Comment: @DerfK Apparently I am hitting the limit because the tgz file is stopping at about 9MB of files (about 3% of the sub 100kb files I was backing up). Perhaps what I need is a sh script that can add files one at a time to avoid the arg limit. Or I could save the output of find to a text file and read that to tar.

Comment: @Xeoncross have you  used `tar tzf backup.tgz` (possibly add `| wc` to get a line count rather than looking file by file) to confirm that you didn't get all the files?  Text tends to compress really well.  You could also run `find /home/user -type f -size -100k | less` and look through it to see if you're finding the files you thought you'd get (or `wc` instead of `less` to compare the line count to the tar command above)

Comment: @skinp: `xargs` can bunch arguments and call the command (`tar --append` in this case) every `-n` files.

Comment: Warning! If you want to use `xargs` or `find -exec {}` with `tar`, you really should be using `tar -A`, and NOT `tar -c`. See my answer for an explanation why.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
find /home/user -type f -size -100k -print0 | xargs -0 tar cvzf tarfile.tar.gz
```

which will be safe for files with spaces in the name too.

Comment: Danger! This will fail if/when the list of files grows longer than the maximum number of command-line arguments. `xargs` executes the given command more than once if it can't fit all the arguments into one command invokation. In this case, each time `xargs` runs another copy of `tar -c`, the tarfile will be overwritten, and the final result will contain only the last batch of filenames that `xargs` received. You really need to do a `tar -A` instead.